# Get an array from Parse query

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview, parse-platform, watchkit

I'm using `Parse` to create this table view, and am trying to figure out how to get the `Parse` table data into an array, so I can pass it into the `WatchKit InterfaceController` to show the exact same thing?

**So I want to show in the WatchKit interface exactly what shows in the iPhone interface.**

*Here is what I have, let me know if I can add anything that would be helpful:*

**`TableVC.m`:**

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aCoder];
    if (self) {
        self.parseClassName = @"na";
        self.textKey = @"dateTime";
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;
        self.paginationEnabled = NO;
    }
    return self;
}
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable
{
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];

    return query;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"RecipeCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    UILabel *homeLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:101];
    homeLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"test"];

    UILabel *dateLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:102];
    dateLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"dateTime"];

    return cell;
}
```

**`Parse data`:**

[image]

**`TableVC.m`:**

[image]

*I already have the basic `WatchKit` files and Storyboard set up.  I hard coded an array to test that it was generally working.  But now I just need to get the data from `Parse` into there, and not sure if I need to do a query and then turn that into a public `array`?*

**EDIT**:

Here is my query:

```
PFQuery *query2 = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"nba"];
[query2 findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        // The find succeeded.
        NSLog(@"Objects 2: %@", objects);
        }
    } else {
        // Log details of the failure
        NSLog(@"Error 2: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}];
```

Here is my NSLog:

`NSLog(@"Objects 2: %@", objects);`

Console:

```
2015-02-09 21:06:30.845 SimpleTable[8373:1284663] Objects 2: (
    "<na: 0x7ff3f8e40880, objectId: cOrjeAmwJh, localId: (null)> {\n    away = Cav;\n    date = \"04/19/2015\";\n    dateTime = \"April 19, 2015, 16:00\";\n    gNumber = 1;\n    home = Bul;\n    matup = \"Ca\";\n    ro = \"Ro \";\n    test = \"Test 2\";\n    tv = T;\n}",
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need the array, fetch it *asynchronously* in a method *outside of* the `queryForTable` method, get it like this:

```
PFQuery *query = [self queryForTable];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        // objects is the array for this table
        NSMutableArray *array = [@[] mutableCopy];
        for (PFObject *object in objects) {
            NSLog(@"we got an object with dateTime = %@", [object objectForKey:@"dateTime"]);
            [array addObject:[object objectForKey:@"dateTime"]];
            // you can prove this with any of your keys: away, number, home, mat up, etc.
        }
    }
}];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, thats sort of the thing I've been trying.  They layed the ground work in the docs for something like that, but I haven't been able to figure out what goes in the `// objects is the array for this table` part.  When I'm using NSLog to log I seem to just be getting pointers, not an array necessarily.  I posted the code above at the end of my original question.  Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like a healthy response from parse, if you read the gibberish, you can see key value pairs for such keys as dateTime, away, gNumber, mat up, etc.  see edit for code to prove that you have an array of pfobjects.

Comment: Right, I kinda had that sort of thing and tried a version of that also, except I was confused because it seemed to just be iterating over it and spitting out all separate objects (as you can see in your code it `NSLog`s one `dateTime` at a time right?), instead of giving me an `array`.  Do you know how you would be able to get an `array` of the `dateTime`s?  Like is there a line or two of code you would add to what you already have that would turn all of those `dateTime`s into an `array`?  Thanks!  I'm almost there!

Comment: @SRMR, see edit. array will be initialized with all of the dates.

Comment: Awesome.  And then do I need to make that array public so the `WatchKit` `InterfaceController.m` can access it?

Comment: Yes. A property of the class where that code resides.

Comment: I guess I'm still not sure how that works: The iPhone side has `TableVC` where I run the `Parse` query, and then the `WatchKit` side has `InterfaceController` with the code and I created a `MyRowController` class that holds the label outlet for the rows.  I would usually pass it via segue or something.  In this case `InterfaceController` is where the code resides, so if I do `@property (nonatomic, weak) NSArray *interfaceArray;` in the `InterfaceController.h` then I'm not sure how `interfaceArray` becomes the array from the `Parse` query if nothing gets passed to it?

Comment: Its tough to understand the organization of your project from the comments, and I've not used watch kit.  But undoubtedly the concepts are the same:  a tableview is always backed by an array.  The tableview has a datasource, which is the class that holds onto that array as a property (most often, this datasource is also the view controller who has the table in its view's hierarchy).

Comment: In some class, maybe the datasource, maybe another, we call parse and fetch an array of parse objects that correspond to rows in the table.  When the find finishes, we set that array property to the received objects and tell the table to reload.  If the fetching view controller is not the view controller with the table, then we segue to it, setting the array data on prepare for segue.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to pass the objects into an array you can do so like this or a variation of:

```
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable
{
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];

    self.someArray = [query findObjects];

return query;
}
```

**REFERNECE**

Comment: I think this is a very bad idea.  What you've done is cause that query to get run *synchronously* whenever the PFQueryTableVC superclass calls the queryForTable method, which is who knows when.